# How to split a data frame into a list of data frame given column names?

Tags: r

I would like to build a function, something like `splitdf(columnA + columnB ~ ., dataframe)`

So that it would return a list of sub data frames for each possible pair of `columnA and columnB`. It is similar to `table` or `xtabs`

So, for

```
> a <- data.frame(x=1:3, y=1:3, z=1:9)
> a
  x y z
1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3
4 1 1 4
5 2 2 5
6 3 3 6
7 1 1 7
8 2 2 8
9 3 3 9
```

I am expecting:

```
x = 1, y = 1, 
      x y z
     1 1 1
     1 1 4
     1 1 7

x = 2, y = 2, 
      x y z
     2 2 2
     2 2 5
     2 2 8

x = 3, y = 3, 
      x y z
     3 3 3
     3 3 6
     3 3 9
```

#### Update

I realized that `split` and `dlply` could work. However neither of them provide me with a good way to manipulate category names? How do I make these names to be meaningful? Like I would like to see `x = 1, y = 1` instead of $`1.1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
> library (plyr)
> dlply(a, .(x, y))
$`1.1`
  x y z
1 1 1 1
2 1 1 4
3 1 1 7

$`2.2`
  x y z
1 2 2 2
2 2 2 5
3 2 2 8

$`3.3`
  x y z
1 3 3 3
2 3 3 6
3 3 3 9
```

**update**

```
> z <- dlply(a, .(x, y))
> names(z) <- dlply(a, .(x, y), function(x) sprintf("x = %d, y = %d", x$x[1], x$y[1]))
> z
$`x = 1, y = 1`
  x y z
1 1 1 1
2 1 1 4
3 1 1 7

$`x = 2, y = 2`
  x y z
1 2 2 2
2 2 2 5
3 2 2 8

$`x = 3, y = 3`
  x y z
1 3 3 3
2 3 3 6
3 3 3 9
```

Comment: @kohske  How does it differ from `split`?

Comment: Note that `plyr` also knows how to handle a formula: `dlply(a, ~x+y)`. That's more like the interface the OP wanted.

Comment: Also, How to make the category names meaningful?

Answer (score 2):

Using base `split` function

```
a <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y = 1:3, z = 1:9)
split(a, f = list(a$x, a$y))
## $`1.1`
##   x y z
## 1 1 1 1
## 4 1 1 4
## 7 1 1 7
## 
## $`2.1`
## [1] x y z
## <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
## 
## $`3.1`
## [1] x y z
## <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
## 
## $`1.2`
## [1] x y z
## <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
## 
## $`2.2`
##   x y z
## 2 2 2 2
## 5 2 2 5
## 8 2 2 8
## 
## $`3.2`
## [1] x y z
## <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
## 
## $`1.3`
## [1] x y z
## <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
## 
## $`2.3`
## [1] x y z
## <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
## 
## $`3.3`
##   x y z
## 3 3 3 3
## 6 3 3 6
## 9 3 3 9
##
```